# React-final-form focus doesn't focus on given field

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-final-form

I was trying to focus on the field when the user press the button, I used `focus('fieldName')`, but it seems doesn't work.

Below is codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-heisenberg-q8dcr?file=/src/App.jsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @erikras responded in [GitHub issue](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/issues/958):

> That's not what form.focus() does. form.focus() tells Final Form that
> a field has received focus.
>
> You need an actual ref to the DOM node. Like this:
> https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-mestorf-26yv8?file=/src/App.jsx

From codesandbox, we should `const ref = useRef();` with Input

```
<Field name="firstName" type="text">
          {({ input }) => (
            <input {...input} placeholder="First Name" ref={ref} />
          )}
</Field>
```

Then `onClick`:

```
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => {
        ref.current.focus();
      }}
      disabled={submitting || pristine}
    >
      Focus
    </button>
```